# Remix.run deployment on Vercel: process not defined error

Tags: environment-variables, vercel, remix, remix.run

I have deployed a remix application on Vercel. Further, I have defined some environment variables in Vercel and want to perform some checks and use env variables in my app:

```js
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    setPaths({
      path: process.env.prod_path,
    })
  }
```

It gives me error, `process is not defined`. I even tried adding `process &&` in the `if` statement, it did not help.

Second, I am unable to even set the env variables locally. I followed [remix docs](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#server-environment-variables) but it gives me `undefined` every time when I `console.log` as mentioned in the docs.

Any guide/pointer towards using environmental variables in remix would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. I was using loader/useLoaderData to access server side environment variables. The problem was that I was trying to call these at component level. Apparently, we can only call them at the route level.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the name of the function (setXXX makes me think this is the setter of a hook), makes me think you are trying to use process.env in the browser, but process.env is only available in server-side code, if you want to use env variables in your react app you can use [this guide](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/envvars#browser-environment-variables) to send the variables from the server side to you react app. If this code is server side code, maybe it's worth making a reproduction in stackblitz so we can have a better look at it.

Comment: I was forwarding them using the `loader` and `useLoaderData` which allow us to access those server side env variables. I figured out the problem. Apparently we can only use loader/useLoaderData at route level. I was trying to do that at the component level.